# Transaction of the contract address

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

I sent ETH to the address of deployment contract,and I mining.But I find this address still doesn't have ETH.
  Can I send ETH to the address of the deployment contract?

Comment: can you post your contract's code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sending ETH to a contract, it triggers the **fallback function** in the contract. If the fallback function isn't `payable` (or isn't defined), the transaction will fail and your contract won't get any ether.

You can either create a payable fallback function, or you can create another function in the contract and mark it as `payable`. Then you can call that function and pass the ETH to the contract.

You can read more about fallback functions in [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7570/whats-a-fallback-function-when-using-address-send)